# Scope NSArray in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray

In GLViewController.m file

At the very top of Implementation

```
NSArray* imageArray ;
```

Then in GLViewController.m inside GLViewController

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder*)coder 
{
 imageArray  = @[ @"baban.jpg",@"cete.jpg",@"cipan.jpg",@"kuc.jpg"];
}
```

Inside drawView in GLViewController.m

```
NSLog(imageArray[0]);  //Fails
```

I've got it declared in the GLViewController.h file too:

```
NSArray* imageArray;
```

I am including GLViewController.h in the GLViewController.m

Comment: Have you checked your init method is being called?

Comment: Init method is being called yes.

Comment: Questions, questions... "In .m file", which file? "in the .h file", which file? which files include it? `initWithCoder:` for which class in which file? "Inside drawView", belonging to which class in which file? `//Fails`, how? You might have two (or more) different variable here, but without details all people can do is guess. Edit your question with these details and someone will probably be able to help you figure out your issue. HTH

Comment: I made some edits thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not clear. E.g. have you declared `imageArray` as an instance variable, a global variable, or possibly both – "At the very top of Implementation" could be read as "top of file", "top of implementation just below `@implementation` in braces" etc.

So we're guessing, let's hope it helps.

First, from what you report; that the init runs but in and instance method accessing the instance variables "fails" in some non-specified way; you *may* have *two* different variables declared in different scopes. Without a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) we can't be more specific. What you can try is to insert:

```
NSLog(@"Loc A imageArray @%p = %p", &imageArray, imageArray);
```

in various locations, where you change the "A" (to "B", "C"...) for each one, where you are accessing `imageArray`. This will print the address of the variable itself, from which you can determine whether you are always referring the *same* variable, and the variable's contents as an address, from which you can determine if the value is changing i.e. whether it's `nil` or the array it references has changed.

Second, you write "I've got it declared in the GLViewController.h file too". You normally do not declared instance variables in the `.h` file, though you can, and you **do not** re-declare global variables in a `.h` and doing so should produce a compiler error – you don't report such an error which leads to the possibility covered above that you may have *two* variables in different scopes.

If you wish to declare a global variable in `file.m` and have it accessible to other code in a different file then in `file.h` you include an `extern` declaration for it:

```
extern NSArray* imageArray;
```

The `extern` states that this line is not declaring the variable itself but that the variable is declared elsewhere and accessible. (You might wonder why you don't add `extern` to functions/methods, in those cases the `extern` is implicit.)

Hope that helps in some way. If this doesn't help at all I suggest you ask a completely new question providing more detail, the minimum reproducible example, etc. (If you edit this question now people may miss the edits thinking they've seen the question.) You can always delete this question to reduce clutter.

Comment: Hello CRD, thank you for your detailed answer. I did an [imageArray retain] in initWithCoder and it actually worked.  Not sure why an array wasn't able to retain its values, should I dereference them as you mentioned above '&'  beforehand?

Comment: It sounds like you have a memory management problem and you are not using ARC, for a `retain` to fix the issue suggests you are doing a `release` somewhere that you should not be doing. You should consider converting the project to ARC. The `&` was only used to print the address of the variable itself (not what was in the variable) as an easy way to determine that you were using the same variable (and not one in a different instance or scope) at all times. Except for debugging purposes as used here you should rarely, if ever, be using the `&` (address of) operator in Objective-C code.